# Android Gps Time

Tags: android, time, gps

I am researching receiving gps time with an android device in order to make an application. I am getting the time from multiple devices and comparing the results. The application will need to get time accurate to within around 5 milliseconds (the comparisons will depend heavily on time). I've been looking around and found some articles such as https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/VwbqlB9ugLg

and

[How do I get the most accurate time with Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759456/how-do-i-get-the-most-accurate-time-with-android)

These articles make it seem like it is not possible but as they are a little older I was wondering if there was any change in technology making it possible or possibly a fancy way around this to have all the devices share the same time?

Code I put together to test out my idea. It is suppose to request a location change every 1 second and update the locations. Two problems occur, first it only updates every ~5 seconds (after reading documentation it seems 5 seconds is the fastest the FusedApi will update) and two it seems the location.getTime is using the device time not gps.

```
package temp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private String mLastUpdateTime;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 1;
    private static final long FATEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.e(TAG, "On Create . . . . .");

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        createLocationRequest();

        Thread myThread = null;

        Runnable myRunnableThread = new CountDownRunner();
        myThread = new Thread(myRunnableThread);
        myThread.start();
    }

    public void doWork() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Log.e("Main", "Inside doWork");
                    TextView txtCurrentDeviceTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DeviceTime);
                    TextView txtCurrentGPSTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GpsTime);
                    Date dt = new Date();
                    String time = dt.toString();
                    txtCurrentDeviceTime.setText(time);
                    Date d = new Date(currentLocation.getTime());
                    txtCurrentGPSTime.setText(d.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class CountDownRunner implements Runnable {
        // @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("Main", "Inside Run");
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    doWork();
                    //Log.e("Main", "After doWork");
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // Pause of 1 Second
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected  void createLocationRequest(){
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnected: Connected - " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.e(TAG, "Location update started ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
        Log.e(TAG, "On Connection Suspended " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Connection failed " + connectionResult.toString());
        stopLocationUpdates();
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged.........");
        currentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.e(TAG, "Location update stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.e(TAG, "MainActivity Started, GoogleApi Connection:  " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, not directly related to your question about time, but since using fused locations, you cannot know if the location is provided by network or GPS. Secondly I just want to let you know that you can get rid of all the GoogleApiClient boilerplate code using a library like https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation, just to let you know

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your input! I agree, I turn off networking before testing the gps time but I use the fusedApi because it is fairly simple to implement. I just started experimenting with gps, time, etc recently and haven't found all the tricks for using it yet. Will definitively look into!